# XML Argument for Email TextView

Tags: android, xml

How to remove yellow backgroud after autofill Email TextView? What argument is responsible for this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3IoK.jpg)

EditText:

```
 <EditText
                android:id="@+id/textEmail"
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />
```

Theme file:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.BudgetManagement" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: can u share your xml code ?

Comment: I added to the question

Comment: can u share your theme file also ? and is this yellow tint only showing on this particular textField or on every textField ??

Comment: This yellow tint is only shown on Email TextFiield.

Comment: Your code looks fine , it shouldn't happen. Is there something else you are doing with the EditText ??

Comment: No. I dont know. I only changed theme (Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar) and set colors.